# Many-to-many relationship with the same model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I make a many-to-many relationship with the same model in rails?

For example, each post is connected to many posts.

Answer (score 288, accepted):

There are several kinds of many-to-many relationships; you have to ask yourself the following questions:

- Do I want to store additional information with the association? (Additional fields in the join table.)
- Do the associations need to be implicitly bi-directional?
  (If post A is connected to post B, then post B is also connected to post A.)

That leaves four different possibilities. I'll walk over these below.

For reference: [the Rails documentation on the subject](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html). There's a section called “Many-to-many”, and of course the documentation on the class methods themselves.

### Simplest scenario, uni-directional, no additional fields

This is the most compact in code.

I'll start out with this basic schema for your posts:

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
  t.string  "name", :null => false
end
```

For any many-to-many relationship, you need a join table. Here's the schema for that:

```
create_table "post_connections", :force => true, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer "post_a_id", :null => false
  t.integer "post_b_id", :null => false
end
```

By default, Rails will call this table a combination of the names of the two tables we're joining. But that would turn out as `posts_posts` in this situation, so I decided to take `post_connections` instead.

Very important here is `:id => false`, to omit the default `id` column. Rails wants that column everywhere **except** on join tables for `has_and_belongs_to_many`. It will complain loudly.

Finally, notice that the column names are non-standard as well (not `post_id`), to prevent conflict.

Now in your model, you simply need to tell Rails about these couple of non-standard things. It will look as follows:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many(:posts,
    :join_table => "post_connections",
    :foreign_key => "post_a_id",
    :association_foreign_key => "post_b_id")
end
```

And that should simply work! Here's an example irb session run through `script/console`:

```
>> a = Post.create :name => 'First post!'
=> #<Post id: 1, name: "First post!">
>> b = Post.create :name => 'Second post?'
=> #<Post id: 2, name: "Second post?">
>> c = Post.create :name => 'Definitely the third post.'
=> #<Post id: 3, name: "Definitely the third post.">
>> a.posts = [b, c]
=> [#<Post id: 2, name: "Second post?">, #<Post id: 3, name: "Definitely the third post.">]
>> b.posts
=> []
>> b.posts = [a]
=> [#<Post id: 1, name: "First post!">]
```

You'll find that assigning to the `posts` association will create records in the `post_connections` table as appropriate.

Some things to note:

- You can see in the above irb session that the association is uni-directional, because after `a.posts = [b, c]`, the output of `b.posts` does not include the first post.
- Another thing you may have noticed is that there is no model `PostConnection`. You normally don't use models for a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association. For this reason, you won't be able to access any additional fields.

### Uni-directional, with additional fields

Right, now... You've got a regular user who has today made a post on your site about how eels are delicious. This total stranger comes around to your site, signs up, and writes a scolding post on regular user's ineptitude. After all, eels are an endangered species!

So you'd like to make clear in your database that post B is a scolding rant on post A. To do that, you want to add a `category` field to the association.

What we need is no longer a `has_and_belongs_to_many`, but a combination of `has_many`, `belongs_to`, `has_many ..., :through => ...` and an extra model for the join table. This extra model is what gives us the power to add additional information to the association itself.

Here's another schema, very similar to the above:

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
  t.string  "name", :null => false
end

create_table "post_connections", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "post_a_id", :null => false
  t.integer "post_b_id", :null => false
  t.string  "category"
end
```

Notice how, in this situation, `post_connections` **does** have an `id` column. (There's **no** `:id => false` parameter.) This is required, because there'll be a regular ActiveRecord model for accessing the table.

I'll start with the `PostConnection` model, because it's dead simple:

```
class PostConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post_a, :class_name => :Post
  belongs_to :post_b, :class_name => :Post
end
```

The only thing going on here is `:class_name`, which is necessary, because Rails cannot infer from `post_a` or `post_b` that we're dealing with a Post here. We have to tell it explicitly.

Now the `Post` model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_connections, :foreign_key => :post_a_id
  has_many :posts, :through => :post_connections, :source => :post_b
end
```

With the first `has_many` association, we tell the model to join `post_connections` on `posts.id = post_connections.post_a_id`.

With the second association, we are telling Rails that we can reach the other posts, the ones connected to this one, through our first association `post_connections`, followed by the `post_b` association of `PostConnection`.

There's just *one more thing* missing, and that is that we need to tell Rails that a `PostConnection` is dependent on the posts it belongs to. If one or both of `post_a_id` and `post_b_id` were `NULL`, then that connection wouldn't tell us much, would it? Here's how we do that in our `Post` model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many(:post_connections, :foreign_key => :post_a_id, :dependent => :destroy)
  has_many(:reverse_post_connections, :class_name => :PostConnection,
      :foreign_key => :post_b_id, :dependent => :destroy)

  has_many :posts, :through => :post_connections, :source => :post_b
end
```

Besides the slight change in syntax, two real things are different here:

- The `has_many :post_connections` has an extra `:dependent` parameter. With the value `:destroy`, we tell Rails that, once this post disappears, it can go ahead and destroy these objects. An alternative value you can use here is `:delete_all`, which is faster, but will not call any destroy hooks if you are using those.
- We've added a `has_many` association for the **reverse** connections as well, the ones that have linked us through `post_b_id`. This way, Rails can neatly destroy those as well. Note that we have to specify `:class_name` here, because the model's class name can no longer be inferred from `:reverse_post_connections`.

With this in place, I bring you another irb session through `script/console`:

```
>> a = Post.create :name => 'Eels are delicious!'
=> #<Post id: 16, name: "Eels are delicious!">
>> b = Post.create :name => 'You insensitive cloth!'
=> #<Post id: 17, name: "You insensitive cloth!">
>> b.posts = [a]
=> [#<Post id: 16, name: "Eels are delicious!">]
>> b.post_connections
=> [#<PostConnection id: 3, post_a_id: 17, post_b_id: 16, category: nil>]
>> connection = b.post_connections[0]
=> #<PostConnection id: 3, post_a_id: 17, post_b_id: 16, category: nil>
>> connection.category = "scolding"
=> "scolding"
>> connection.save!
=> true
```

Instead of creating the association and then setting the category separately, you can also just create a PostConnection and be done with it:

```
>> b.posts = []
=> []
>> PostConnection.create(
?>   :post_a => b, :post_b => a,
?>   :category => "scolding"
>> )
=> #<PostConnection id: 5, post_a_id: 17, post_b_id: 16, category: "scolding">
>> b.posts(true)  # 'true' means force a reload
=> [#<Post id: 16, name: "Eels are delicious!">]
```

And we can also manipulate the `post_connections` and `reverse_post_connections` associations; it will neatly reflect in the `posts` association:

```
>> a.reverse_post_connections
=> #<PostConnection id: 5, post_a_id: 17, post_b_id: 16, category: "scolding">
>> a.reverse_post_connections = []
=> []
>> b.posts(true)  # 'true' means force a reload
=> []
```

### Bi-directional looped associations

In normal `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations, the association is defined in **both** models involved. And the association is bi-directional.

But there is just one Post model in this case. And the association is only specified once. That's exactly why in this specific case, associations are uni-directional.

The same is true for the alternative method with `has_many` and a model for the join table.

This is best seen when simply accessing the associations from irb, and looking at the SQL that Rails generates in the log file. You'll find something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM "posts"
INNER JOIN "post_connections" ON "posts".id = "post_connections".post_b_id
WHERE ("post_connections".post_a_id = 1 )
```

To make the association bi-directional, we'd have to find a way to make Rails `OR` the above conditions with `post_a_id` and `post_b_id` reversed, so it will look in both directions.

Unfortunately, the only way to do this that I know of is rather hacky. You'll have to manually specify your SQL using options to `has_and_belongs_to_many` such as `:finder_sql`, `:delete_sql`, etc. It's not pretty. (I'm open to suggestions here too. Anyone?)

Comment: Thanks for the nice comments! :) I've made some further edits. Specifically, the `:foreign_key` on the `has_many :through` is not necessary, and I added an explanation on how to use the very handy `:dependent` parameter for `has_many`.

Comment: @Shtééf even mass assignment(update_attributes) will not work in case of bi-directional associations eg: postA.update_attributes({:post_b_ids =>[2,3,4]}) any idea or workarounds ?

Comment: Very nice answer mate 5.times { puts "+1" }

Comment: @Shtééf I learned a lot from this answer, thank you! I tried to ask and answer your bi-directional association question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493368/many-to-many-self-join-in-rails/25493403#25493403

Answer (score 21):

To answer the question posed by Shteef:

### Bi-directional looped associations

The follower-followee relationship among **Users** is a good example of a Bi-directional looped association.  A **User** can have many:

- followers in its capacity as followee
- followees in its capacity as follower.

Here's how the code for [user.rb](https://github.com/jbmilgrom/LEAf/blob/master/app/models/user.rb) might look:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # follower_follows "names" the Follow join table for accessing through the follower association
  has_many :follower_follows, foreign_key: :followee_id, class_name: "Follow" 
  # source: :follower matches with the belong_to :follower identification in the Follow model 
  has_many :followers, through: :follower_follows, source: :follower

  # followee_follows "names" the Follow join table for accessing through the followee association
  has_many :followee_follows, foreign_key: :follower_id, class_name: "Follow"    
  # source: :followee matches with the belong_to :followee identification in the Follow model   
  has_many :followees, through: :followee_follows, source: :followee
end
```

Here's how the code for [follow.rb](https://github.com/jbmilgrom/LEAf/blob/master/app/models/follow.rb):

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, foreign_key: "follower_id", class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followee, foreign_key: "followee_id", class_name: "User"
end
```

The most important things to note are probably the terms `:follower_follows` and `:followee_follows` in user.rb. To use a run of the mill (non-looped) association as an example, a **Team** may have many :`players` through `:contracts`. This is no different for a **Player**, who may have many `:teams` through `:contracts` as well (over the course of such **Player**'s career). But in this case, where only one named model exists (i.e. a **User**), naming the through: relationship identically (e.g. `through: :follow`, or, like was done above in the posts example, `through: :post_connections`) would result in a naming collision for different use cases of (or access points into) the join table. `:follower_follows` and `:followee_follows` were created to avoid such a naming collision. Now, a **User** can have many `:followers` through `:follower_follows` and many `:followees` through `:followee_follows`.

To determine a **User**’s :followees (upon an `@user.followees` call to the database), Rails may now look at each instance of class_name: “Follow” where such User is the the follower (i.e. `foreign_key: :follower_id`) through: such **User**’s :followee_follows. To determine a **User**’s :followers (upon an `@user.followers` call to the database), Rails may now look at each instance of class_name: “Follow” where such **User** is the the followee (i.e. `foreign_key: :followee_id`) through: such **User**’s :follower_follows.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks! (I recommend also listing the database migrations; I had to glean that info from the accepted answer)

Answer (score 6):

If anyone came here to try to find out how to create friend relationships in Rails, then I would refer them to what I finally decided to use, which is to copy what 'Community Engine' did.

You can refer to:

https://github.com/bborn/communityengine/blob/master/app/models/friendship.rb

and

https://github.com/bborn/communityengine/blob/master/app/models/user.rb

for more information.

TL;DR

```
# user.rb
has_many :friendships, :foreign_key => "user_id", :dependent => :destroy
has_many :occurances_as_friend, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id", :dependent => :destroy
```

..

```
# friendship.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
```

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @Stéphan Kochen,
this could work for bi-directional associations

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many(:posts,
    join_table: 'post_connections',
    foreign_key: 'post_a_id',
    association_foreign_key: 'post_b_id')

  has_and_belongs_to_many(:reversed_posts,
    class_namy: Post,
    join_table: 'post_connections',
    foreign_key: 'post_b_id',
    association_foreign_key: 'post_a_id')
 end
```

then `post.posts` && `post.reversed_posts` should both works, at least worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For bi-directional `belongs_to_and_has_many`, refer to the great answer already posted, and then create another association with a different name, the foreign keys reversed and ensure that you have `class_name` set to point back to the correct model. Cheers.

Comment: Could you show an example in your post? I've tried multiple ways as you suggested, but can't seem to nail it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone had issues getting the excellent answer to work, such as:

> (Object doesn't support #inspect)
>   =>

or

> NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for :Mission:Symbol

Then the solution is to replace `:PostConnection` with `"PostConnection"`, substituting your classname of course.