# Joining a table with itself via many-to-many in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models

In my database, OptionSets are associated with other OptionSets.  If I was joining two separate tables I would create a simple join table.  However, Rails likes to have its foreign keys named <singular_table_name>_id, i.e. optionset_id.  However, if I am joining the table with itself I obviously cannot give the two tables the same name.  How do I deal with this?

```
create_table :optionsets_optionsets do |t|
  t.column :optionset_id, :integer
  t.column :dependent_optionset_id, :integer # how do i deal with this?
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dude there was a perfect answer to your question:

[Many-to-many relationship with the same model in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168442/many-to-many-relationship-with-the-same-model-in-rails)

Comment: Dude how did I not see that?  Thanks.