# Nest model form with many to many relationship on same model, in nested model...Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know my title was a tongue twister so I'll do my best to explain whats going on.

Firstly, I have a model. Lets call it posts.

Then I have a second model, which is essentially a join table, linking two different posts together. We can call that post connections.

I accomplished this by following the instructions here: [Many-to-many relationship with the same model in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168442/many-to-many-relationship-with-the-same-model-in-rails) for Uni-directional, with additional fields.

The code for those models looks like:

```
class PostConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post_a, :class_name => :Post
  belongs_to :post_b, :class_name => :Post
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many(:post_connections, :foreign_key => :post_a_id, :dependent => :destroy)
  has_many(:reverse_post_connections, :class_name => :PostConnection,
      :foreign_key => :post_b_id, :dependent => :destroy)

  has_many :posts, :through => :post_connections, :source => :post_b
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_connections
end
```

This so far works fine - and when I create post connections manually using rails admin, they work just great.

The problem now, is I'd like to make a form which has post connections nested under posts.

I've been trying to follow the rails cast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1

But even the first few steps didn't work. I didn't get an error. Nothing showed up where the fields were supposed to populate. (I'm wondering if it had to do with:

```
  3.times { @post.post_connections.build }
```

)

Is there a more complicated way that I should be going about this based on the models?

Comment: Did you miss the `=` in `<%=` ? In Rails 3, you need to use the `=` for `form_form` and `fields_for`.

Comment: Hey Zabba, that was it! Please respond with that in an answer so you can get the points! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you miss the = in <%= ? In Rails 3, you need to use the = for form_form and fields_for.

:D