# Records in join table destroyed automatically in HABTM association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, has-and-belongs-to-many, destroy

Let's say I have an association where User has and belongs to many Roles.  When I destroy the user, is the record in the join table automatically removed as well?  Or do I need to use :dependent => :destroy?  What about if I destroy a Role?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belong_to_many :roles # need to use :dependent => :destroy to remove join record?
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belong_to_many :users # need to use :dependent => :destroy to remove join record?
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The join table entry is removed but the Role or User is not removed. You can't add a dependent destroy clause to has_and_belongs_to_many, but you can add them to the relations in your join model if you want to. For example to destroy a role when the associated join table entry is removed you would do the following:

```
class RolesUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: I thought one of the points of HABTM was that there IS no intermediate model.  So this wouldn't work unless the RolesUsers model existed.

Comment: HABTM requires an intermediate model/table otherwise the relation can't exist in a relational database. For the task that @keruilin is attempting to accomplish he needs to either append to his existing RolesUser model or create it.

Comment: To clarify: HABTM requires the intermediate *table*, but not the extra model. You'll use `has_many/through` if you need extra controls or fields in the intermediate model.

Comment: Read [this excellent post by shteef](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2168528/356895) to learn more about additional attributes in a join table.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed - When you delete a user or role, all of the records in the join table with that user / role will also get deleted