# Ruby on rails Cross-model editing via many-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, many-to-many, editing

I've been tracking the SO site as my rails progress has developed and it is a good source of information.
I am writing an application to maintain a bunch of hosts and their associated warranty.
contracts
A host can have many contracts and a contract can apply to many hosts.
So I have three classes: `Host`, `WarrantyContract` and `HostWarranty`.
The `HostWarranty` model has FK references to the host and `WarrantyContract` as well as a comments field.

What I need to be able to do is manage the contents of the `host_warranties` table (assetid, warranty_contract, comments) through the host and `warranty_contract` pages, so that when editing a host's details, I can apply one or more contracts; when I edit a contract I can indicate what host(s) it applies to.

I have been exploring using `has_many`, `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `has_and_belongs_to_many` ([Many-to-many relationship with the same model in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168442/many-to-many-relationship-with-the-same-model-in-rails) being the main source so far) but I am struggling with how I develop the view `_form` template; most examples I have seen utilise the `fields_for` method, whereas what I need is a `<select>` list of names and id's.

I'm particularly after suggested solutionsm but more an idea of what kind of api areas I should be looking at or googling for.

Comment: Any chance you can distill that text down to a specific problem? I think I get at what you are asking but its not really clear.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking how to multi select from existing records?
If that is the case then you have an number of options.
1) You could present a list of items (contracts?) with check boxes so the user can tick the items they want

2) You could present a drop down multi select box to pick multiple items from

3) You could present a searchable input field that the user types into and as they type a list is presented that match the input criterea

All these options are covered on the Railscasts website in one shape or another

http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields
http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association
http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes

Should be enough there to get you started

Comment: This is for a data collection exercise. I have been trying all the documented method for getting this working and the application is now so broken and I's so disillusioned with ruby that I have to conclude that HABTM doesn't actually work and that it will be much quicker for me to complete each asset-warranty detail for all 250 hosts once cell at a time that try to get it working in rails.

Comment: The railcast fairly neatly describes part of what I need and I may, at some point in the future revisit this, but I also need to perform the operation from both hosts and contracts.
Right now, too many people need this data and since they live by spreadsheets, I have failed miserably in persuading them to use a proper data driven approach.

Comment: This very nearly actually worked and if I didn't have primary key fields called 'id' rather than the Rails norms then (and I do have one really stupid column name), it probably would have been successful.
I have, however, hit one of those brick-wall errors ('undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass') from which I'm unlikely to recover.
I do really appreciate the suggestion and this seems the best way to solve this kind of question.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you got past this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from jamesw was fantastic. Perfect. I can get some sleep now knowing that this is the way to do it. And I should be able to apply this technique to the other tables that I need to manage.
The railscast is absolutely spot on.
Thabk you very much.

Comment: Which of the 3 casts did you go for? Any chance of an accepted answer :)?