# Rails: Add information in a many-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, one-to-many

I have set up a many-to-many association between users and rotas. I am trying to also store who the creator of a particular rota is.

**Class User**

```
  has_many :rotazations
  has_many :rotas, :through => :rotazations
```

**Class Rota**

```
  has_many :rotazations
  has_many :users, :through => :rotazations, :order => 'name ASC'
```

**Class Rotazation**

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :rota

  before_create do |rotazation|
    rotazation.creator_id = rotazation.user_id
  end
```

When a rota is created, I have successfully set the creator_id in the rotazation table to have the id of the user who created the rota. My question is, how do I access it:

```
rota.creator
```

---

**My attempt**

I have tried to add the following:

*Rota Class*

```
...
belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User", :through => :rotazations, :foreign_key => "creator_id"  
...
```

*User Class*

```
has_many :created_rotas, :class_name=> "Rota", :through => :rotazations, :foreign_key => "creator_id"
```

However, this doesnt work. Any ideas how to achieve rota.creator work? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this posts: [Many-To-Many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168442/many-to-many-relationship-with-the-same-model-in-rails) This accepted answer there has helped me out when I had a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you create a new line in your `rotazations` table you add the `user_id` to the `creator_id`, which is an attribute on the `Rotazation`.

However, the `rotazations` table is a combination of `user_id` and `rota_id` just to solve the many-to-many relationship. If I am thinking it right, the `creator_id` will always be the same as `user_id`. So, you actually have redundante data:

```
| user_id | rota_id |creator_id |
| 1       | 1       | 1         |
| 2       | 1       | 2         |
| 1       | 2       | 1         |
| ...     | ...     | ...       |
```

In order to know who has created a new `Rota` you can add a new attribute to the `rotas` table, lets say `creator`.

When you create a new rota, you can save the `user_id` into this new attribute:

```
@rota = Rota.new
@rota.creator = current_user.id
```

Comment: very good point. So its a many-to-one relationship between a User and a Rota. I normally create rotas using: user.rotas.create

I was wondering, can I implement a call back when the rota is created to automatically have the creator field point to the user that created it?

Comment: you can do `user.rotas.create` because of the has_many through association, otherwise you had to do it in parts as user and rota are not directly connected. I think the best option for you is to include a hidden_field in your form. I am assuming you have a current_user helper, so you can include `<% f.hidden_field :creator, :value => current_user.id %>`. Each time you create a new rota, the `creator` will store the `id` of the current user.