# Collection select with many-to-many in same model in rails gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a weird rails database/form problem.

I got 1 table with Courses, and 1 table Prerequisites, which has 2 columns that both hold Course_ids (columns are called "course_a_id" and "course_b_id").

In the Course model I have this:

```
:has_and_belongs_to_many(:prerequisites,
:join_table => "prerequisites",
:foreign_key => "course_a_id",
:association_foreign_key => "course_b_id",
:class_name => "Course")
```

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168442/many-to-many-relationship-with-the-same-model-in-rails/2168528#2168528)

This works if I put the prerequisites in by Console, something like this:

```
Course.find(3).prerequisites = [Course.find(1), Course.find(2)]
```

This form field however does not let me put prereqs in the DB:

```
<%= f.label :prerequisite, "Prerequisites" %>
<%= f.collection_select(:prerequisites, Course.all, :id, :name,
    {:multiple => true}, :multiple => "multiple") %>
```

Gives this error after posting with one option selected with value 1:

```
"Course(#-631146998) expected, got String(#77208170)"
```

and in the parameter dump:

```
"prerequisites"=>["",
"1"]}
```

I have no clue how that "" ended up in the params and can't figure out another way to create the form field. I think my model is set up correctly.

Comment: Try this `<%= f.collection_select(:prerequisite_ids, Course.all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true}) %>` and in your `Course` Model add `:prerequisite_ids` to `attr_accessible`