# Association through non-standard column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a `Friends` model with `user_id` and `friend_id`...both are id's back to specific users.

What I'd like to able to do is something like this:

```
@relationship = Friend.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
@relationship.friend.username
```

Where I can basically pull the user through the `friend_id` column in the same way I can do `@relationship.user.username`.

How would I setup my associations to pull that off?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just a many-to-many situation.

I think there is a perfect solution in [Many-to-many relationship with the same model in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168442/many-to-many-relationship-with-the-same-model-in-rails)

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `class_name` if your column doesn't reflect the convention expected:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Note that I modified the model name to `Friendship` to better reflect the use of this model.  Also, you can make it easier for yourself if you revise your `User` model to look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships

  has_many :friendships_of, :class_name => 'Friendship', :foreign_key => :friend_id
  has_many :friends_of, :through => :friendships_of, :source => :user
end
```

Now to see all the user's friends:

```
current_user.friends.map(&:username)
```

And to see who has 'friended' the user:

```
current_user.friends_of.map(&:username)
```