# Many-To-Many relation with same model - 2 join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, join

I have a model named Course.each course has two kind of many-to-many relation with other courses. so I need two join tables. how can i implement it in rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the following (looong) answer for a pretty comprehensive list of possible ways to do HABTM associations between objects of the same model: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2168528/454094

Once you decide on whether to use a "normal" join table or use the `:through` option with a model inbetween, defining two different HABTM associations shouldn't be more complicated than using different names and join tables / models for them. E.g.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many(:friends,
    class_name: "Person",
    join_table: "friend_connections",
    foreign_key: "person_a_id",
    association_foreign_key: "person_b_id")

  has_and_belongs_to_many(:foes,
    class_name: "Person",
    join_table: "foes_connections",
    foreign_key: "person_a_id",
    association_foreign_key: "person_b_id")

end
```

Note: as the linked answer states, the above associations will be one-way. E.g. `bob.friends << alice` will not automatically make `bob` appear in `alice.friends`. Depending on your particular project, that may or may not be a dealbreaker. Still, hope this helped.