# How to create/update objects in Rails in a many-to-one self-referential model using nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

My Rails 4 app has a topic model that allows many-to-many self-referential relationships.  I set up the model based on [this fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493368/many-to-many-self-join-in-rails/25493403#25493403) on creating a model for many-to-many self joins, and it appears to work if I populate the relationships table manually.  Let's use that model for the purposes of the question:

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # follower_follows "names" the Follow join table for accessing through the follower association
  has_many :follower_follows, foreign_key: :followee_id, class_name: "Follow" 
  # source: :follower matches with the belong_to :follower identification in the Follow model 
  has_many :followers, through: :follower_follows, source: :follower

  # followee_follows "names" the Follow join table for accessing through the followee association
  has_many :followee_follows, foreign_key: :follower_id, class_name: "Follow"    
  # source: :followee matches with the belong_to :followee identification in the Follow model   
  has_many :followees, through: :followee_follows, source: :followee
end
```

follow.rb:

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, foreign_key: "follower_id", class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followee, foreign_key: "followee_id", class_name: "User"
end
```

Once I manually populate the Follow table, I can successfully get data from the model using methods like @user.followers and @user.followees.

Where I'm stuck is in how to create the **Follow** relationships (Follower or Followee) using ActiveRecord properly, in the "Rails way."

In the controller, what would the code look like to create a new **User** and assign it an existing **Followee** (or multiple **Followees** at the same time using nested attributes?

I've been trying approaches that pass vars from the view (multi-select input) like:

```
user_params = {"user"=>"name","followees_attributes"=>{"id"=>{"1","2"}}}
```

And then in users_controller.rb:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

but with no luck, and I'm not sure if I'm even in the right ballpark here (new to Rails.)  It feels too simple, but I get that feeling a lot with Rails...hehe.  If I'm close but you need to see error messages, please let me know.

**EDIT**

I'm not sure if this is the "right" way to do this (doesn't feel like it), but I got it working by separating the nested attributed vars from the model, and then manually creating the relationship.

```
params = {"user"=>"name"},{"followees_attributes"=>{"id"=>{"1","2"}}}
```

And then in users_controller.rb:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
@user.followees << User.find(1)
@user.followees << User.find(2)
@user.save
```

Naturally you'll need some duplicate checking in there to make sure the relationship doesn't already exist, but fundamentally this gets the job done.  Any better solutions out there?

Comment: You should add a unique index to both columns of `follows` to prevent duplicates.

Comment: Yep, will do.  Thanks!