# Mutual relationships in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-models

I'm trying to allow users in my app to be mutual friends with one another via friend requests and I'm a little confused with the how the relationships work... When a friendship is created by one user and accepted by the other, I would like the friendship to be visible from both users (obviously).

I'd like to achieve an implementation that allows me to do something similar to the following:

```
user1 friend requests user2
user2 accepts
user1.friends now contains user2
user2.friends now contains user1
```

Here's what I have so far, but I've read some weird things about nested has_many :through relationships

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :friendships
 has_many :friends, :class_name => "User", :through => :friendships
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :users, :limit => 2
end
```

Is this a viable implementation? If not, what could I change/improve? I'd like to avoid 2 rows representing one relationship if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is a has_and_belongs_to_many relation, but to the same table, kind of like as described in detail by [Many-to-many relationship with the same model in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168442/many-to-many-relationship-with-the-same-model-in-rails). However, since you want the relation to be bi-directional ("my friends are all also friends with me"), you have two options:

1. Use a single join table, each row of which links two user_ids, but insert two rows for each friendship.

   ```
   # no need for extra columns on User
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :friendships
     has_many :friends, through: :friendships
   end

   # t.belongs_to :user; t.belongs_to :friend
   class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
     belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
   end

   u1 = User.create!
   u2 = User.create!
   u3 = User.create!

   # make users 1 and 2 friends
   u1.friendships.create(friend: u2)
   u2.friendships.create(friend: u1)        

   # make users 2 and 3 friends
   u2.friendships.create(friend: u3)
   u3.friendships.create(friend: u2)        

   # and now, u1.friends returns [u1],
   # u2.friends returns [u1, u3] and
   # u3.friends returns [u2].
   ```
2. Use a single record, but hackery to locate who you're friends with:

   ```
   # no need for extra columns on User
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :friendships_as_a, class_name: "Friendship", foreign_key: :user_a_id
     has_many :friendships_as_b, class_name: "Friendship", foreign_key: :user_b_id

     def friends
       User.where(id: friendships_as_a.pluck(:user_b_id) +          friendships_as_b.pluck(:user_a_id))
     end
   end

   # t.belongs_to :user_a; t.belongs_to :user_b
   class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user_a, class_name: "User"
     belongs_to :user_b, class_name: "User"
   end
   ```

That's not the cleanest way to do it, but I think you'll find there isn't really a particularly clean way when set up like that (with a denormalized table). Option 1 is a much safer bet. You could also use a SQL view to hit the middle ground, by generating the mirror entries for each friendship automatically.

### Edit: Migration & usage in an API

Per the OP's comment below, to use Option 1 fully, here's what you'd need to do:

```
rails g migration CreateFriendships
```

Edit that file to look like:

```
class CreateFriendships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  create_table :friendships do |t|
    t.belongs_to :user
    t.belongs_to :friend
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Create the Friendship model:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
end
```

Then on your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships, class_name: 'User'

  # ...
end
```

And in your API, say a new FriendshipsController:

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])

    User.transaction do # ensure both steps happen, or neither happen
      Friendship.create!(user: current_user, friend: friend)
      Friendship.create!(user: friend, friend: current_user)
    end
  end
end
```

Which your route for looks like (in `config/routes.rb`):

```
resource :friendships, only: [:create]
```

And a request to would look like:

```
POST /friendships?friend_id=42
```

Then you can refer to `current_user.friends` whenever you want to find who a user is friends with.

Comment: Really helpful but this is for an API and I'm just a little confused what the create action would look like for a controller given that I'm using devise and current_user refers to the current user... I get how to create the friendship but how do I properly associate it with the user and soon-to-be-friend -> also unsure how the migration would look

Comment: @Riptyde4: see my Edit to the answer. I added concrete code samples for Option 1, which is my recommended solution.

Comment: You're a saint! Thanks, that clears things up beautifully

Answer (score 1):

You'd use a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships, -> { where(status: "accepted") }
end

#app/models/friendship.rb
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"

  enum status: [:pending, :accepted]
  validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :friend, message: "You can only add a friend once" }

  def decline
    self.destroy
  end

  def accept
    self.update status: "approved"
  end
end
```

The above is a [`self-referential join`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins), allowing the following:

```
@user   = User.find params[:id]
@friend = User.find params[:friend_id]

@user.friends << @friend
```

--

This will add a new `friendship` for the user, with its default `status` set to `pending`. The `@user.friends` association is set so that *only* `accepted` friends appear from a call.

Thus, you'll be able to do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
  resources :friendships, only: [:index, :destroy, :update], path_names: { destroy: "remove", update: "accept" }
end

#app/controllers/Frienships_controller.rb
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user       = User.find params[:user_id]
    @friendship = @user.friendships
  end

  def update
    @user       = User.find params[:user_id]
    @friendship = @user.friendships.find params[:id]
    @friendship.accept
  end

  def destroy
    @user       = User.find params[:user_id]
    @friendship = @user.friendships.find params[:id]
    @friendship.decline
  end
end

#app/views/friendships/index.html.erb
<%= @friendships.pending.each do |friendship| %>
  <%= link_to "Accept", user_friendships_path(user, friendship), method: :put %>
  <%= link_to "Decline", user_friendships_path(user, friendship), method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm just a little confused how to use this, what would I do for the create method and migration???