# In Rails, How should I allow users to create an ordered list of other users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

Suppose I have a User model, and I'd like to allow each user to choose their "top friends" that are also users, in order of favoriteness. This way a user can have a "best friend" and a "3rd best friend" and so on. I think what I'm looking for (correct me if this is a bad path to go down) is a habtm within the User model, with the added dimension of an order to them.

The end goal is to allow me to do something like:

`@user.favorite_users` => an ordered list of their favorite users.

`@user.favorite_users.each do |user|
 //iterate through each user in order from best friend to worst friend 
end`

I'm using Ruby 2.3.0, Rails 4.2.

Comment: You might be interested in the Acts As List gem (https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list). Allows for easy implementation. I haven't used this for a many-to-many relationship, but I'd imagine you'd be best using a `has_many through` relationship and attaching `position` here. Hope that helps!

Comment: you need to use `has_many though:` not habtm as it does not allow you store additional data on the join table. Adding the "favoriteness" to the join table is  trivial but setting up a many to many to the same table is quite difficult. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168442/many-to-many-relationship-with-the-same-model-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, -> { order 'friendships.order ASC'}, through: :friendships
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'  
end
```

`@user.friends` will give you list of users ordered by `order` in `friendships`

Comment: This is simple and effective - then friendships table has order:integer friend_id:integer user_id:integer, and indexes on user_id and friend_id. The order can be easily noted and changed using user.friendships.(...) It's working for me.