# How to correctly associate a model with 2 different objects?(Rails 4)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Before I ask my question, I will give some context.

In my Rails 4 app, I have 3 models in question.

```
Clubs has_many Teams. 
Teams belong_to Clubs
Clubs has_many Schedules. 
Schedules belong_to Clubs.
```

The Relevant Columns for Teams in the Database:

```
:win(integer)
:loss(integer)
:tie(integer)
```

The Relevant Columns for Schedules in the Database:

```
:team1
:team2
```

The schedule object is supposed to show 2 teams versus each other. In the form for the schedule object, I will make
**Club.teams** available in 2 separate drop-down boxes, so the user can select `:team1` and `:team2`.

Upon the creation of a Schedule object, I'd like to make a toggle box available which you can click on later to state which team won the match.

Example Setup for the div of a Schedule Object:

```
Team 1                    |(Box1)|(Box2)|(Box3)|                       Team 2
```

If Box1 is clicked for example, that would mean Team 1 won and I would automatically adjust the Win/Loss/Tie Columns in the Teams Table(Increase :win by 1 for Team 1 and increase :loss by 1 for Team 2). Box2 means tie and Box2 means Team 2 won. This will be done by ajax.

Finally, for my question, how do I associate `:team1` and `:team2` columns in the Schedule object with the appropriate Team objects in the Teams table in order to manipulate their columns with the toggle box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you need to create a  join table referencing the same model, which in your case is team

```
create_table "team_matches" do |t|
  t.integer "team_a_id", :null => false
  t.integer "team_b_id", :null => false
  t.integer  "win_or_lose"
end
```

and in the TeamMatch Model you will do something like that

```
class TeamMatch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team_a, :class_name => :Team
  belongs_to :team_b, :class_name => :Team
end
```

and in the Team model

```
    class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :team_matches, :foreign_key => :post_a_id, :dependent => :destroy
      has_many(:reverse_team_matches, :class_name => :TeamMatch,
      :foreign_key => :team_b_id, :dependent => :destroy)

      has_many :teams, :through => :team_matches, :source => :post_b
    end
```

and you are good to go, create two teams and do something like that and see if it works in your console

```
team1 = Team.create(...) #whatever your attributes put them in the create function 

team2 = Team.create(...) #whatever your attributes put them in the create function 

team1.teams << team2
team1.team_matches #Here the record the joins team1 and team2 will appear, along with win_or_lose_attribute

team1.team_matches.first.update(win_or_lose: 1) #or whatever value you want to specify win, tie or lose
```

Comment: for more illustration you can check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168442/many-to-many-relationship-with-the-same-model-in-rails)

Comment: it looks nice, ill test too.

Comment: Hello! Not too familiar with join tables. Would this table replace the Schedules table then? Also, if I was to associate the team_matches with a Club, do i just put the club_id in as a foreign key for team_matches? I'd like to display all the team matches like Club.team_matches, where they can only be associated to 1 club.

Comment: @kpaul I think you have to make a join table, as the team can have one or matches with one or more team, your association here is many to many, so you have to make a join table if this is the logic you want to implement

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for your help!