# Rails: many-t-many relationship between various models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible, in Rails (4 or 5) to set this kind of relationship between models:

- Model A has many Models B
- Model B has many Models B

I don't know if there is a good approach to these relationships, or if it's better to change the model data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Many-to-many relationship with the same model in rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168442/many-to-many-relationship-with-the-same-model-in-rails)

Comment: @Gerry the problem is that it's not only the many-to-many with the same model. The same model (B) can belong to another one, at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The first relationship is a standard one-to-many (or even many-to-many) relationship, and the second one "Model B has many Models B" fits [Self Joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html):

> In designing a data model, you will sometimes find a model that should
>   have a relation to itself. For example, you may want to store all
>   employees in a single database model, but be able to trace
>   relationships such as between manager and subordinates. This situation
>   can be modeled with self-joining associations:
>
> ```
> class Employee < ApplicationRecord
>   has_many :subordinates, class_name: "Employee",
>                           foreign_key: "manager_id"
>
>   belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee"
> end
> ```