# Rails migrations: many-to-many relationship between the same class | Interpersonal Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many, rails-migrations

I want to connect two People with the help of Relationship.

```rb
Person:
* id
* name

Relationship:
* person_a_id
* person_b_id
* connection # an enum with values like "colleagues", "friends", "siblings", etc
```

I want to accomplish a couple of things:

1. I have created 2 people. I want the second person to be included when I query for `Person.first.people` **and vice versa**! (i.e the first person shall be included when I query for `Person.second.people`). I was close to achieve this with `has_and_belongs_to_many :(people|reversed_people)`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46230787/6030239
2. Relationship which connects the two has a connection value of `friends`. I want to create a `has_many :friends` method, such that the second person will appear in Person.first.friends query **and vice versa!**

Answer (score 0):

First off - I wouldn't use HABTM here, but instead a named join table (called Relationship) with it's own model and use `has_many :people, through: :relationships`.

> 1. I have created 2 people. I want the second person to be included when I query for Person.first.people and vice versa! (i.e the first person shall be included when I query for Person.second.people). I was close to achieve this with has_and_belongs_to_many :(people|reversed_people): https://stackoverflow.com/a/46230787/6030239

You can achieve this with a single activerecord relationship (either has-many through or HABTM) by adding two rows for each relationship (one in each direction). For example:

```rb
def add_bi_directional_relationship(first:, second:, type:)
  Relation.create!(person_a: first, person_b: second, connection: type)
  Relation.create!(person_a: second, person_b: first, connection: type)
end

# first.people => [second]
# second.people => [first]
```

Activerecord associations are designed to query a table by a foreign key, so to use them in a straightforward way you need a table where the value you want to query is going to be in a single column.

However, why do you need it to be done via an activerecord association? You can write a method that does the query you need.

```
class Person
  has_many :forward_people, through: :relations, #...
  has_many :reversed_people, through: :relations, #...
  def people
    forward_people + reversed_people
    # or build the joins in SQL strings or Arel
  end
end
```

Or lots of other potential solutions, depending on your needs.

> 2. Relationship which connects the two has a connection value of friends. I want to create a has_many :friends method, such that the second person will appear in Person.first.friends query and vice versa!

Not sure I totally understand this... but if you take the first approach of adding a relationship for each direction, then you can write a method like:

```rb
def friends
  people.where(relations: {connection: 'friends'})
end
```

You can also do this with another activerecord relationship... but I wouldn't recommend defining multiple activerecord associations for the same foreign keys. An alternative approach could be to define a `.friends` scope that would allow you to do `Person.first.people.friends`.

In general these goals are difficult to accomplish because you're specifying an implementation (an activerecord association that returns specific values) without indicating why you need it to be done like / what problems you're trying to solve with it. Activerecord associations are helpful to a point, but they also introduce a layer of abstraction that can add complexity/confusion. Discussing the actual business/application needs you want to solve (e.g. a report that shows X, a view that renders X, or a form that saves X) would allow people to suggest alternative approaches that might be a better fit what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't define assocations in ActiveRecord where a the foreign key is one of two columns you can set this up by adding an additional join table:

```
class Person
  has_many :personal_relationships
  has_many :relationships, through: :personal_relationships
  has_many :related_people, through: :relationships,
                            source: :persons
end

class Relationship
  has_many :personal_relationships
  has_many :persons, through: :personal_relationships
end

class PersonalRelationship
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :relationship
  validates_uniqueness_of :person_id, scope: :relationship_id
end
```

`has_and_belongs_to_many` is not relevant here. It really only handles the most trivial cases and falls flat on its face if there is even the vaguest hint of complexity.

You would create a relationship between two users with:

```
@relationship = Relationship.new
@relationship.persons << user_1
@relationship.persons << user_2
```

This creates two rows in the `personal_relationships` table.

While this might seem kind of wonky it gives you a single association that can be properly eager loaded and treated as a homogenous collection. The con is that you need more database rows and you'll need to use some more advanced techniques like custom constraints if you want to ensure that a relationship can only have to people on the database level.

Comment: Hello, max! Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I like your approach, however the validation doesn't seem to be working. I was able to create multiple relationships between the same people, which is not an intended outcome. Could you please describe, what your suggested validation does? And how could I prevent creation of multiple connections between the same people?

Comment: I have added a simple connection enum to Relationship model, and created `friends` method for Person. It seems donkey. Could you suggest an improvement to it in your answer? `def friends people_ids = [] relationships.friends.each do |r| r.personal_relationships.where.not(person_id: id).each do |pr| people_ids << pr.person_id end end Person.where(id: people_ids) end`